# In mongoose, what is the difference between save(), insertOne() and updateOne(),when I want to add something new to a field that is already made?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

for example I have a schema

```
 const  listSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
      name:String,
      items:Array
    });

const List=mongoose.model("List",listSchema);
```

and I made a document
const list=New List({
name: "list1",
items:[item1, item2,item3]
});

and then later I wanted to add a new item called item 4 so I used

```
List.findOne({name:list1},function(err,foundList){
foundList.items.push(item4);
foundList.save();
```

I know it might be a stupid question but it's confusing me. When I use `.push` I essentially added a new item inside the array, therefore I would have 4 items inside the array now. So here comes the question: why when I used .save(), it's not adding 4 extra items but instead it only adds the item4 that I wanted to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insertOne()` allows you to insert a NEW document into a collection. While `save()` creates a new document by calling the instance of that document, meaning the model/Object that has been created. However, If you have fetched an existing document and call .save() to it, (just like how you did in your example). it will simply updates the document with the changes you've made with it instead. Now, `updateOne()` basically will let you update an existing document by matched parameters.

Examples:
`insertOne()`

```
let newDoc = {name:'List2',items =['item1','item2']} // creating a new object to be inserted into the collection 
List.insertOne({newDoc},(err,result)=>{
})
```

`updateOne()`
Let's say you have an existing document in your collection like: `{ name: "list1", items:[item1, item2,item3] }`
you can update the fields by doing:

```
List.insertOne({
                 name:'list1' // meaning you are looking for a document which has a name of 'list1'
               },
               {
                 $push:{items:'item4'// we are using push since we know it's an array field
                 // you can also do
                 // {$set:name:'new name'} // if you want to update a string, date etc2x field
                },(err,result)=>{
})
```

`.save()`
You can creat a new document by doing:

```
let newList = new List({
                      name:'list2'
                      items: ['item1','item2','item3'] 
                      })
newList.save();
```

But using it to UPDATE an EXISTING document:
In using `.save()`, you may need to explicitly specify the change or which property/field you have changed. Mongoose deals nested or deep object properties differently. Here is the documentation on mongoose website: [check here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)

In your case, you need to do an extra step before saving, which is to specify the property/path you have modified as such:

```
List.findOne({name:'list1'},
             (err,foundList) => {
               foundList.items.push(item4);
               foundList.markModified('items')
                foundList.save()
             })
```

Comment: but in the findOne, i already specify the name which is the list1, so do I still need to use markModified?

Comment: and I'm not exactly sure the differences between save() or insertOne() or maybe even updateOne(), since in this situation, I am essentially adding a new document into one of the field, so can you briefly explain to me the differences and how save() works?And also does it matter which one I use for this kind of situiton? Thank you and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: you might have mixed up these 2 functions. can you show me you inserOne() code?

Comment: Sorry I am still learning about mongoose, so I don't  know exactly which one to use in this situation. I've watched a tutorial that shows me to use the .save() function, and out of curiosity I asked this question. so I don't really have the code for insertOne() function. Thank you very much!

Comment: ive updated my answer. does that make sense? or do you need further examples

Comment: Yes!!! That totally makes sense to me. But can you provide me some examples or explain to me when to use save(), updateOne() and insertOne().Since I am still new to mongodb and I need more experiences.Also, I know using UpdateOne() and using $set can create a new field if it is not created.  Again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I kind of thought through the process, so essentially if I want to add a new field, I wouldn't use insertOne, but I can use save() Or UpdateOne() to either create a new field or add things into the new field(), is this correct?

Comment: if you say field, are you referring to  a document property? if you want to add new `field` you have to declare the field in your schema