# Mongoose updateOne vs save methods

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

There are few ways to update the document record in MongoDB database.
With the `User` model defined I can find the `user` first, then modify its attribute and save it with the `save()` method:

```
let user = await User.findOne({"email": "user@email.com"});
user["email"] = "another@email.com";
await user.save();
```

Another option would be to use `updateOne` method instead of `save`:

```
await user.updateOne({"email": "another@email.com"});
```

Why would I choose to use the `updateOne` method over the `save`? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In mongoose, what is the difference between save(), insertOne() and updateOne(),when I want to add something new to a field that is already made?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63185666/in-mongoose-what-is-the-difference-between-save-insertone-and-updateone)

Comment: Because it's one line over 3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your first example it requires 2 separate queries to your database, so less performant. One to find the document, and then another to save (update it). Though the benefit of doing it this way is if you have validation setup in your schema, then it would check the validation before updating.

The second one you only do one query and it's done. This however won't check your validations. Though you can opt-in by passing `runValidators:true`:

```
await user.updateOne({"email": "another@email.com"}, {"email": "another@email.com"}, { runValidators: true });
```